# h.264 and mpeg header

Tags: android, h.264, rtp, mpeg-4

I'm trying to develop code for mpeg/h.264/RTP streaming. I'm quite new to all this , so maybe my question is a bit silly.  I'm capturing video from the mobile camera (android) and  I want to stream it. Looking in the net I've found many similar things, what I think I'm supposed to do is take out the mpeg4 header from the stream, this is , take of the first 40 bytes of the stream and after that I should find de NAL unit length in the next 4 bytes, but I'm not finding it, and I don't know why.

My stream looks like that :

mpeg4 header

```
0000001866747970336770340000030033677034336770360000000877696465000000006d646174
```

and then

```
3c911716be6679e1e001e7aff0000000800000000000000000000000000000003c4877.......
```

So my NAL unit length is 3c911716...which obviously is not my NALu length

Is there anything I'm missing ???

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all MPEG variant codecs are H.264. Check out what exactly the codec is.

Also, even if it is H.264, it doesn't always have NAL units. This is could be raw h.264 file packed in different container like 3gpp or MP4.

Try GSpot application to figure this out.